# Sharepoint Online - External User Share

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, external-users

I am having some issues sharing a wiki made on sharepoint online 365 to external users. 
Some information, the site I am trying to open access to is a subsite of my main sharepoint online site. It is set up using the enterprise wiki template.

So the settings for my main site:
https://Site_name.sharepoint.com/default.aspx

In Sharepoint Admin Center > Sharing:
[image: Sharepoint Sharing]

**NOTE: Sharepoint Administrators group contains my account.**

Now for that site in Site Collections, checked and selecting sharing:

[image: Sharepoint Site Collections]

Then I go into my Site and select **"Share"**
And I get the following window:

[image: Share Window]

As you can see I don't see the ability to create a link. I have tried the sharing link in the cog menu, same thing. I have tried opening site permissions and sharing I get the same window.

Can someone please help, this is driving me spare. I have the same results on the subsite that I am attempting to share publicly.